# Substantial derivative of density in the derivation of mass conservation equation.

Tags: fluid-dynamics

We are all taught the derivation of the mass conservation using a fixed Eulerian control volume in a typical fluid dynamics course.

That is, first we think about the *total rate of change of mass* in that control volume. 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_V\rho dV
$$
Next, we say that *in the absence of sinks or sources*, the fluid that enters this volume contributes to the increase. The expression is :
$$
-\int_{\partial V}\rho\vec{u}\cdot \hat{n}dA
$$

Now these expressions are equal, 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_V\rho dV = -\int_{\partial V}\rho\vec{u}\cdot \hat{n}dA
$$

to give us the integral form of the mass equation.

Now, to get the differential form, we use the gauss-divergence theorem and do some strange manipulation to the total derivative on the LHS :

$$
\int_{V}\left[\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + \nabla\cdot(\rho \vec{u})\right]dV = 0
$$

So, my question is how did the substantial derivative for density turn into a partial derivative?

I understand that if you consider the total mass of the volume, it's essentially changing only with time. 
i.e.
$$
\frac{dM}{dT} = \frac{\partial M}{\partial T}
$$

where M is the mass of the control volume.

But how do you explain the use material derivative with density above?

Shouldn't this be true :

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_V\rho dV = \int_V\frac{d\rho}{dt}dV = \int_V\left[\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + \vec{u}\cdot\nabla\rho\right]dV
$$

Can this only be explained by $$\vec{u}\cdot\nabla\rho=0$$?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Understand that the substantial derivative exists for only field variables i.e. functions that vary with position vector **x** and time t.

Thus, 
$$
\frac{DM}{DT}
$$

doesn't really make sense.

For a fixed control volume the mass can only vary with time.